# Canon TS6300 auto on

Tags: networking, wireless, printing

I want my printer, Canon TS6300 on WiFi, to switch on when data is sent to it. Windows has the ij printer utility which allows what they call "auto on" but not so with Linux.

Can this be done at the printer or is there a program to do it that I haven't found?

Comment: This isn't a Linux Q&A site, but a Ubuntu site.  Why ask here?  the only OS you specifically mention is off-topic Windows.  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "Wake on LAN" may do it.